# Changing Relationships based on value of a field in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table that I would like to link three other tables too, I realized it is impossible to do this so I decided to find a way to do it with VBA. I grabbed some code that I really hope will work and have been editing it to make it work with my specific needs

```
Option Compare Database

 Function changeRel()

    If Players.Cond = "Quest" Then
        Dim dbs As DAO.Database
        Dim rel As DAO.Relation

        Set dbs = CurrentDb

        Set rel = dbs.CreateRelation("QuestRel", "Players", "Player Quests", dbRelationDeleteCascade)
        rel.Fields.Append rel.CreateField("PlayerID")
        rel.Fields("PlayerID").ForeignName = "PQuestID"

        dbs.Relations.Append rel
        dbs.Relations.Refresh

    ElseIf Players.Cond = "Level" Then
        Dim dbs As DAO.Database
        Dim rel As DAO.Relation

        Set dbs = CurrentDb

        Set rel = dbs.CreateRelation("LevelRel", "Players", "Player Levels", dbRelationDeleteCascade)
        rel.Fields.Append rel.CreateField("PlayerID")
        rel.Fields("PlayerID").ForeignName = "PLevelID"

        dbs.Relations.Append rel
        dbs.Relations.Refresh

    ElseIf Players.Cond = "Stat" Then
        Dim dbs As DAO.Database
        Dim rel As DAO.Relation

        Set dbs = CurrentDb

        Set rel = dbs.CreateRelation("StatRel", "Players", "Player Stats", dbRelationDeleteCascade)
        rel.Fields.Append rel.CreateField("PlayerID")
        rel.Fields("PlayerID").ForeignName = "PStatsID"

        dbs.Relations.Append rel
        dbs.Relations.Refresh

    Else
        'Do nothing

End Function
```

I've never coded in VBA before, I have no idea what the `Option Compare Database` means, it was just there. I am pretty sure I need a subroutine though I'm confused about what it is.

Could someone tell me how I could make this function run every time the value of cell `Players.Cond` changes?

Comment: [Option keyword on docs.SO](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3992/vba-option-keyword/13937/option-compare-binary-text-database#t=20161121223654120041)

Comment: You should not regularly change DB relationships based on data values. Table relationships maintain the structural integrity of a database and should be adjusted only once during database design period. Else you can break a lot of application logic and records management.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this to pull related data from all 4 tables:

```
SELECT Players.PlayerID, [Player Quests].PQuestID, [Player Levels].PLevelID, [Player Stats].PStatsID
FROM (((Players 
  LEFT JOIN [Player Quests] ON Players.PlayerID = [Player Quests].PQuestID) 
  LEFT JOIN [Player Levels] ON Players.PlayerID = [Player Levels].PLevelID) 
  LEFT JOIN [Player Stats] ON Players.PlayerID = [Player Stats].PStatsID)
```